# how to get image and show on same page using php

Tags: php

This is my `photos.html` file

I want to get image path from this and I want to show it on same page I know I will save it like `photos.php` but how can I do it on same page, please help me.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <strong>Upload Files</strong> 
        <small>upload any file</small>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <!-- Standar Form -->
        <h4>Select files from your computer</h4>
        <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="js-upload-form">
            <div class="form-inline">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="file" name="files[]" id="js-upload-files" multiple>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" id="js-upload-submit">Upload files</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I will be very thankfull to you, thanks.

Comment: If I understand correctly, as soon as you upload your image, you want your image to be displayed on the form itself before submission. Right?

Comment: no brother after submission i want to display it on same page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should refer to the following links:

[Multiple image upload preview before image uploading to the server using Jquery](http://www.2my4edge.com/2015/10/multiple-image-upload-preview-before.html)

[Upload Multiple Images With Image Preview Using jQuery,Ajax And PHP](http://talkerscode.com/webtricks/upload-multiple-images-with-image-preview-using-jquery-ajax-php.php)

**Sample Example:**

*HTML code:*

```
<input id="imageupload" type="file" multiple />
<div id="preview-image"></div>
```

*Javascript code:*

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#imageupload").on('change', function () {

   var countFiles = $(this)[0].files.length;

   var imgPath = $(this)[0].value;
   var extn = imgPath.substring(imgPath.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();
   var image_holder = $("#preview-image");
 image_holder.empty();

   if (extn == "gif" || extn == "png" || extn == "jpg" || extn == "jpeg") {
      if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {

         for (var i = 0; i < countFiles; i++) {

             var reader = new FileReader();
             reader.onload = function (e) {
                 $("<img />", {
                     "src": e.target.result,
                         "class": "thumbimage"
                 }).appendTo(image_holder);
             }

             image_holder.show();
             reader.readAsDataURL($(this)[0].files[i]);
          }

       } else {
         alert("It doesn't supports");
       }
   } else {
       alert("Select Only images");
   }
});
</script>
```

Comment: i did it already images are storing and showing but i want to show like image slider